# How to Unwrap Json data in angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable, httpclient

I have a Json data in this format

[image]

I want to parse this data in angular typescript when I am calling the rest API. How to do it.

Here this part is my java class object which I want to convert to my model class array.

```
"gameId": 66,
"kashScore": 0,
"samScore": 1,
"wonBy": "Sam",
"createUserId": 0,
"lastModifiedUserId": 0,
"creationDate": "2020-04-20T14:05:44.263+0000",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-20T14:05:44.264+0000",
"sessionId": 1000,
"count": null
```

My model class

[image]

And this information is for tracking pagination.

[image]

I tried something like this, but it gives error as:-

[image]

Comment: Can u change your obvservable propery Fifa[] to GetResponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is just an array. The data that represents `Fifa[]` is the first item in the response array.

The `HttpClient` won't magically convert it for you. If you want to return `Fifa[]` from your service, then you need to map your response to that type.

```js
return this.http.get<any[]>(fifaUrl).pipe(
  map((response: any[]) => response[0])
);
```

EDIT

You have stated that you want to return all information from the response. In that case you should return an object that implements `GetResponse` from service function (and probably think about a more suitable name).

```js
fetchAllGamesRecordPaginate(
  pageNumber: number, pageSize: number
): Observable<GetResponse> { 
  const fifaUrl = ${this.baseUrl}/demo/pageNumber/${pageNumber}/pageSize/${pageSize}; 
  return this.httpClient.get(fifaUrl).pipe( 
    map((response: any[]) => {
      const pagination = response[1];
      return {
        fifa: response[0],
        totalRecord: pagination.totalRecord,
        pageSize: pagination.pageSize,
        pageNumber: pagination.pageNumber,
        totalPages: pagination.totalPages
      };
    })
  ); 
}
```

Here I am mapping the response array to an object that implements `GetResponse`.

Comment: It worked and how will I access the pagination record

Comment: Where to you want it to go? There is no pagination on the `Fifa[]` data type

Comment: Wherever you access it, you will get it by doing `response[1]`

Comment: fetchAllGamesRecordPaginate(pageNumber: number, pageSize: number): Observable<Fifa[]> {
    const fifaUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/demo/pageNumber/${pageNumber}/pageSize/${pageSize}`;
    // return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(fifaUrl);
    return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(fifaUrl).pipe(
      map((response: any[]) => response[0]));
  }

Comment: So, can you please :) edit your answer to show be how I can get both response[0] and response[1], I am new to typescript and having problems with syntax to:).

Comment: I've edited my answer. This is the long way of doing it, but hopefully the clearest

Comment: Awesome @Kurt Hamilton. Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the method to just return an `Observable<Fifa[]>` you should use a map operator on your `Observable`:

```
return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(fifaUrl).pipe(
  map((response) => response.fifa)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

update the return type to `Observable<GetResponse>` then you need to map the respond to GetResponse structure

```js
fetchAllGamesRecordPaginate(pageNumber:number,pageSize: number):Observable<GetResponse>{ 
  const fifaUrl = ${this.baseUrl}/demo/pageNumber/${pageNumber}/pageSize/${pageSize}; 
  return this.httpClient.get(fifaUrl)
    .pipe(([fifa,paginationInfo]) => (
      {
       fifa ,
       ...paginationInfo
       }
     )
    ); 
}
```

> the api return an array with two items the first is the fifa[] and the
>   second  is an object with pagination information

Comment: So what will be in GetResponse

Comment: No I want what code will go in GetResponse Interface

Comment: the api return  an array of two items so you need to map the array to `GetResponse `

Comment: the updated answer will give you a respond with structuer as `GetResponse `

Comment: But you haven't defined GetResponse interface that you are returning

Comment: what do you mean `But you haven't defined GetResponse` I have map the respond from an array to an object with the same structure of the interface